# How to create the Minecraft launcher button?

Tags: launcher, minecraft

I am trying to run a small minecraft server via Ubuntu desktop 12.04 for my kids. I got minecraft installed and running, but don't want to run via the Terminal all the time. I'm trying to pin a Minecraft button to the launcher and am running into trouble. Here's what I've tried:

1. Main Menu (alacarte?) but can't find the icon anywhere; can't drag it from the Main Menu list either.
2. When that didn't work, I tried creating `minecraft.desktop` & `minecraft.sh` files.
3. I was able to download and get a .png file on the launcher but it won't launch anything.

Here's a rundown of all the commands and scripting I've done:

1. Terminal Script that does work:

   ```
   sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~$ cd /home/sara/MCserver
   sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
   ```
2. "Main Menu" command script:

   ```
   java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -Xincgc -jar /home/sara/MCserver/minecraft.jar
   ```
3. minecraft.sh script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   cd $(home/MCserver "$0")
   java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
   ```
4. minecraft.desktop script:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=MineCraft
   Comment=
   Exec=/home/sara/MCserver/minecraft.sh
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/Minecraft_Block.svg
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   ```
5. All files are stored in the *MCserver* folder. When I open the folder on Launcher, it starts at *Home* -- then *MCserver* is one of the folders within *Home* (I don't see *"Sara"* as a subdirectory of *Home* here -- sometimes I see it when accessing other files somewhere).

---

@edwin:  here's the copy of `la /home/sara`

```
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ la /home/sara
.bash_history  examples.desktop       .ICEauthority       .profile
.bash_logout   .fontconfig            .java               Public
.bashrc        .gconf                 .local              .pulse
.cache         .gnome2                MCserver            .pulse-cookie
.config        .goutputstream-KIZ8WW  minecraft.desktop~  Templates
.dbus          .goutputstream-QXYAXW  minecraft.png       .thumbnails
Desktop        .goutputstream-UZYSWW  .mission-control    Videos
.dmrc          .gstreamer-0.10        .mozilla            .Xauthority
Documents      .gtk-bookmarks         Music               .xsession-errors
Downloads      .gvfs                  Pictures            .xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: Are you trying to just play Minecraft or are you trying to set up a Minecraft server to play on? In the beginning you say you are trying to set up a Minecraft server, but in your Minecraft.sh script you are trying to launch the .jar of the game itself instead of the .jar to start a server to play on.

Comment: Ah. Look like I'm mixing 2 diff things … I'm trying to setup/run a server. I don't want to start the server in the Terminal. I was hoping to create a shortcut so my kids could start & shutdown the server without my help. Can this easily be done?

Answer (score 1):

The script should read:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME/MCserver
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
```

After writing it, you should make it executable, so open a terminal and if the script
is in a file called `minecraft.sh` (check if the casing is right, upper and lower 
case matter!):

```
$ cd $HOME/MCserver
$ chmod +x minecraft.sh
```

Finally you must put `minecraft.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` or
in `$HOME/.local/share/applications` (not both, only one of the two):

- Do this if you want all users to have the Minecraft icon:

  `$ sudo mv minecraft.desktop /usr/share/applications`
- Or do this if you want only the current user to have the Minecraft icon:

  `$ mv minecraft.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications`

The launcher should appear in the Unity Dash (so you can search for it typing "Minecraft"). Then you can just drag it to the panel.

Comment: You don't need to put it in `/usr/share/applications` here. For personal launchers, one can put them in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications` which defaults to being `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: @edwin (and dobey) -- thanks for your fast response & help.  I believe I followed your instructions well. Although now I have 2 MC icons and neither one launches anything. Or maybe it does and I have no idea how to tell. I'm not sure what to do next. Any advice? I copied and entered the script as provided. Although I think I had to change HOME to home since that's how it appears on my system -- I may have kept the last "mv" edit with HOME. Would that affect anything?

Comment: @edwin -- here's copy of my Terminal screen after successfully entering your script:                                           sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ $ cd $HOME/MCserver
$: command not found
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ $ chmod +x minecraft.sh
$: command not found

sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~$ cd $home/MCserver
bash: cd: /MCserver: No such file or directory
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~$ cd ~/MCserver
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ chmod +x minecraft.sh
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ mv minecraft.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications

Comment: Notice that you must type `$HOME` and not `$home`, case matters. Could you please post the result of `la /home/sara` and `la /home/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: @edwin -- I'm running into character limitations, so I'm posting the "la /home/sara" request in the original question as an "edit." Hope that's ok . . .

Comment: @edwin:  here's the 2nd one you requested --  sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ la /home/.local/share/applications
ls: cannot access /home/.local/share/applications: No such file or directory
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~/MCserver$ cd
sara@sara-Dimension-4300:~$ la /home/.local/share/applications
ls: cannot access /home/.local/share/applications: No such file or directory

Comment: Oh yeah, I cut and pasted your original comments from your text.  So "HOME" was capitalized but it said something like directory not found and didn't work.  That's why I manually switched it to lower case.

Comment: Make sure the script reads `$HOME` (with the dollar sign, with lower case won't work). Just to check: 1. You created the desktop file (`minecraft.desktop`); 2. You put the desktop file in the folder `/home/sara/.local/share/applications`; 3. And the script `minecraft.sh` is in `/home/sara/MCserver`.

Comment: ok @edwin, I've checked and 1. Yes, minecraft.desktop was created, 2. Yes, it's in /home/sara/.local/share/applications, and 3. Yes, minecraft.sh is in /home/sara/MCserver

Comment: I should let you know that I tried creating this launcher button via alacarte and those files are in the same directory as minecraft.desktop . . . could that be messing up things?

Comment: Delete the files created by alacarte (for minecraft, do not modify the others!). Also, in a terminal, what happens if you enter `/home/sara/MCserver/minecraft.sh`?